# Power of a negative decimal raised to a decimal

Tags: java, math

the Javadoc of [java.lang.Math.pow(double a, double b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) states:

- If the first argument is finite and less than zero:

  - if the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the result is NaN.

This means a call to `Math.pow(-Math.E,-1.1d)` yields NaN.

Why isn't Math.pow() returning the inverse `1/e^1.1`? Is there an error in my reasoning?

Thanks!

Comment: because `1/e^1.1` is equal to `e^(-1.1)` and not `(-e)^(-1.1)`.

Comment: This feels like it's really a maths question rather than a Java question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there's an issue with your logic.  Please go and read about complex numbers.

The problem is that a negative base raised to a non-integer negative power results in a complex number, not a real double.  There's an imaginary part that `Math.pow` can't deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why it should return `1/e^1.1`? This will be `1/(-e)^1.1` which is not real number.